# Simple C++ Syntax Correction

Tags: c++

Anything wrong with the following C++ code?

```
int i;
int n;
cout << "a";
cin >> n;
int player[i];
for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
     player[i] = n;
}
```

Comment: What does your compiler tell you?

Comment: variable 'player' set but not used;

'i' may be used uninitialized in this function

Comment: int i is not initialized. what is the value of i?

Comment: The correct code depends on what you want the program to do. But yes, there are things wrong with that code (use of uninitialized variables, use of VLAs, etc.).

Comment: @LwinHtooKo:u can't use variable as subscript of array

Comment: @Ravindrabagale int size = 10; int * arr; arr = new int[size]; that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same functionality, I would do:

```
#define PLAYER_SIZE 4
//Or you can go:
//const int PLAYER_SIZE = 4;
int n = 0; //Don't *need* to = 0 in this case, but good practice.
cout << "a";
cin >> n;
int player[ PLAYER_SIZE ];
for( int i = 0; i < PLAYER_SIZE; ++i )
{
     player[i] = n;
}
```

Since i<=3 is hard coded in this case, there's no need to go any higher then 4.

Comment: Why not make the for loop: `for ( int i = 0; i < PLAYER_SIZE; ++i )`?

Answer (score 0):

```
you can't declare index of array as variable
```

declare some size, like

```
int player[10];
```

or use preprocessor directives

```
#define i 10
int player[i];
```

totally

```
#define i 10
int main()
{
int j;
int n;
cout<<"a";
cin>>n;
int player[i];
for(j=0;j<=3;j++)
{player[j]=n;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize i to something and declare it const then using it to delcare the size of a static array is ok.

If you want the size to be determined at run time you will need to use the new operator and deal with heap memory and pointers.

```
const int i = 4; // whatever size
int player[i];

int n;
cin >> n;
cin.ignore(); // important if you plan on using cin again, also think about adding some input checking

for (int x = 0; x < i; ++x ) // for god sakes use ++x
     player[x] = n;
// take note your setting every int in player to the same value of n
```

Just to clean it up a little

```
const int arraySize = 4;
int playerArray[arraySize];

int input = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i )
    {
    cin >> input;
    cin.ignore(); // still no error checking
    playerArray[i] = input;
    }
```

This code allows for different ints to be inputted for each int in the array.